# How to use "using" keyword for variadic template

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates

I have a variadic template class that can take any number of variables in the constructor and also a `std::tuple/std::pair` and so forth.

I would like to use this wrapper for functions with varying return types.

For example:

```
class f1
{
    using output = double;
    output operator() { do_smth };
}
class f2
{
    using output = std::tuple<double,int>;
    output operator() { do_smth };
}



template <typename... Types>
class OutputType
{
    std::tuple<Types...> m_val;
public:
    OutputType(std::tuple<Types...>&& val) : m_val(val) {};
    OutputType(Types&& ... val) : m_val(std::forward<Types>(Types)...) {};
};
```

Now in a third class I would like to declare using like this:

```
template <typename F>
class dummy
{
    using Output = typename OutputType(typename F::Output));
}
```

How do I declare the above using statement so it does the correct thing also for `dummy<f2>`?

(i.e `OutputType<double,int>` and not `OutputType<std::tuple<double,int>>`)

Comment: Could you provide a code that at least work for `f1`? Your code contains plenty typographic mistakes... What you need here is probably to specialize `dummy` for `std::tuple`.

Comment: You might be able to convert the tuple to a pack and send that pack to `OutputType`.  Not sure how that would look.  There is plenty of stuff here already though on converting a tuple to a parameter pack.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand correctly your question (?), you can define a type-traits as

```
template <typename ... Types>
struct oTypes
 { using type = OutputType<Types...>; };

template <typename ... Types>
struct oTypes<std::tuple<Types...>>
 { using type = OutputType<Types...>; };
```

and then define `dummy` as follows

```
template <typename F>
struct dummy
 { using output = typename oTypes<typename F::output>::type; };
```

The following is a full compilable example

```
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>

struct f1
 {
   using output = double;

   output operator() ()
    { return 0.0; }
 };

struct f2
 {
   using output = std::tuple<double,int>;

   output operator() ()
    { return { 1.0, 2 }; }
 };

template <typename ... Types>
class OutputType
 {
   private:
      std::tuple<Types...> m_val;

   public:
      OutputType(std::tuple<Types...>&& val) : m_val(val)
       { }

      OutputType(Types&& ... val) : m_val(std::forward<Types>(val)...)
       { }
 };

template <typename ... Types>
struct oTypes
 { using type = OutputType<Types...>; };

template <typename ... Types>
struct oTypes<std::tuple<Types...>>
 { using type = OutputType<Types...>; };

template <typename F>
struct dummy
 { using output = typename oTypes<typename F::output>::type; };

int main()
 { 
   static_assert( std::is_same<dummy<f1>::output,
                               OutputType<double>>::value, "!");
   static_assert( std::is_same<dummy<f2>::output,
                               OutputType<double, int>>::value, "!!");
 }
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was asking. That's a pretty clever solution. I thought about using decltype() but could not figure out how to write it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

A helper template like

```
template<typename ... Types>
struct add_tuple {
    using type = std::tuple<Types...>
};

template<typename ... Types>
struct add_tuple<std::tuple<Types...>> {
    using type = std::tuple<Types...>
};
```

Which changes OutputType to something like

```
template <typename... Types>
class OutputType
{
    typename add_tuple<Types...>::type m_val;
public:
    OutputType(typename add_tuple<Types...>::type&& val) : m_val(val) {};
    OutputType(Types&& ... val) : m_val(std::forward<Types>(Types)...) {};
};
```